# Angular internationalization with database REST calls returning bilingual content

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate

I'm converting my bilingual web app into Angular. It's an interface where the user selects the content that they wish to view, and once selected the data is loaded from a REST api, which is hooked into an SQL database. The way it's set up is the database calls return content in two languages. For example, the JSON response for the `TableComponent` would be:

```json
GET /api/tables/1
{
    "title": "Hello",
    "titleFr": "Bonjour",

    "time": "05:23 PM",
    "timeFr": "17:23",

    "content": "I am a grapefruit",
    "contentFr": "Je suis un pamplemousse"
}
```

Different Components receive different values, but always for both languages. Only one language is shown at a time, but there's a button at the top allowing the user to instantly switch the content's language. From what I understand, to have this kind of behavior I should use [`ngx-translate`](http://www.ngx-translate.com/). Being totally new at this, I'm not really sure where to begin. I read some of the docs; what it sounds like is I either have to have the content and its translation in JSON files bundled with the app, or I make HTTP calls to a database which returns the translated content.

Neither of those approaches work with my current setup. As mentioned, all database calls return the text for both languages, instead of having them split up. Is there a way to achieve localization without needing to split them up?

The reason I have it this way is in my original implementation, I loaded all the data from the database, and chose which HTML template to display depending on the selected language. For example with the `TableComponent`, if English was selected then the template would use `title, time, content`, and if French then `titleFr, timeFr, contentFr`. To  have all my components know the current language and detect language changes was a little cumbersome, which is why I want to take advantage of internationalization libraries.

The reason I have it this way is my web app is meant to be used in both languages. Meaning, users will switch back and forth very regularly. As such, I want to reduce the http requests. When they fetch the data, they'll have the content for both languages. This should make switching quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

I do recomment splitting them up and using Angular's `i18n` module ([see this page](https://angular.io/guide/i18n)). If not splitting them up is a strict requirement, I suggest creating a translation service, so that your components just call that service providing which language to use. Something like:

*translation.service.ts*

```
@Injectable()
export class TranslationService {
  constructor() {}

  async public getTranslation(language: string): Observable<any> {
    // Get your text from database (assuming it's an Observable)
    return db.get().pipe(
      map(translations => {
        // Just a suggestion, you can also have a mapping for better syntax
        if (language === 'french') {
          return {
            title: translations.titleFr,
            time: translations.timeFr,
            content: translations.contentFr
          }
        }

        // Otherwise, return default language
        return {
          title: translations.title,
          time: translations.time,
          content: translations.content
        }
      }),
      // You can add shareReplay from rxjs/operators to cache results
      shareReplay(1)
    );
  }
}
```

And then in your component, you can just access data from this service and take advantage of Angular's modularity.

*component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { TranslationService } from './path-to/translation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.scss']
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public texts: {
    title: string;
    time: string;
    content: string;
  }

  constructor(
    private readonly translationService: TranslationService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.translationService.getTranslations('french').subscribe(result => this.texts = result);
  }

}
```

This way, your components are not even aware of the contents of the text, your service takes care of handling the translation, and it's easily expandable for more languages as well.

Comment: As I mentioned, I can't bundle translations with the app (which if I understand correctly is what angular's i18n uses), as the text comes from an API. That's why I found ngx-translate. I'll consider your translateservice. Thanks

Comment: The problem with your service is it only gives one language back. The point of my setup is one http request gives both languages. This way switching the language is instantaneous and doesn't wait for the request to return. I clarified in my question.

Comment: You can update the service to get multiple languages as well, just pass on the language you want on the component. You could make use of RxJS `shareReplay` and cache your database results, [see this link for info](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay), so you don't need to call it everytime.

Comment: The problem with this approach is I have different types of components which accept different fields from the database. I just gave one example in my question. The TranslationService wouldn't know what data to map (depending on the current language), since it doesn't know which fields which components are expecting from the db.